# Replacing the library react-native-toast-message leading icon

Tags: typescript, toast

I am trying to use the library `react-native-toast-message` and replacing the type `error` by using a different SVG image file from the local assets folder.

```
const errIcon: ImageSourcePropType = {
  uri: '../assets/tick.svg'
};

export const toastConfig = {
  error: ({ text1, props, ...rest }) => (
    <BaseToast
      {...rest}
      leadingIcon={errIcon}
      contentContainerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 15 }}
      text1Style={{
        fontSize: 15,
        fontWeight: '400'
      }}
      text1={text1}
    />
  )}
```

The icon is not showing. I am wondering what is the right way to replace the leading icon?

Reference
[react-native-toast-message](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-toast-message)

Answer (score 0):

`leadingIcon` and `trailingIcon` are of type `ImageSourcePropType` which is:

```
export type ImageSourcePropType = ImageURISource | ImageURISource[] | ImageRequireSource;
```

where

```
export interface ImageURISource {
/**
 * `uri` is a string representing the resource identifier for the image, which
 * could be an http address, a local file path, or the name of a static image
 * resource (which should be wrapped in the `require('./path/to/image.png')`
 * function).
 */
uri?: string;
/**
 * `bundle` is the iOS asset bundle which the image is included in. This
 * will default to [NSBundle mainBundle] if not set.
 * @platform ios
 */
bundle?: string;
/**
 * `method` is the HTTP Method to use. Defaults to GET if not specified.
 */
method?: string;
/**
 * `headers` is an object representing the HTTP headers to send along with the
 * request for a remote image.
 */
headers?: { [key: string]: string };
/**
 * `cache` determines how the requests handles potentially cached
 * responses.
 *
 * - `default`: Use the native platforms default strategy. `useProtocolCachePolicy` on iOS.
 *
 * - `reload`: The data for the URL will be loaded from the originating source.
 * No existing cache data should be used to satisfy a URL load request.
 *
 * - `force-cache`: The existing cached data will be used to satisfy the request,
 * regardless of its age or expiration date. If there is no existing data in the cache
 * corresponding the request, the data is loaded from the originating source.
 *
 * - `only-if-cached`: The existing cache data will be used to satisfy a request, regardless of
 * its age or expiration date. If there is no existing data in the cache corresponding
 * to a URL load request, no attempt is made to load the data from the originating source,
 * and the load is considered to have failed.
 *
 * @platform ios
 */
cache?: 'default' | 'reload' | 'force-cache' | 'only-if-cached';
/**
 * `body` is the HTTP body to send with the request. This must be a valid
 * UTF-8 string, and will be sent exactly as specified, with no
 * additional encoding (e.g. URL-escaping or base64) applied.
 */
body?: string;
/**
 * `width` and `height` can be specified if known at build time, in which case
 * these will be used to set the default `<Image/>` component dimensions.
 */
width?: number;
height?: number;
/**
 * `scale` is used to indicate the scale factor of the image. Defaults to 1.0 if
 * unspecified, meaning that one image pixel equates to one display point / DIP.
 */
scale?: number;
}
```

and like any Image component you can not use SVGs for it.